# Get Facebook profile picture via PHP (user-id)/picture

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I work on a website with uses PHP SDK to fetch user info including the user-picture.
`{user-id}/picture` stops working when I get some traffic.
I get a null response from facebook when I have good traffic.
By null response I mean they return nothing. Just an empty page.

Facebook says that they are not allowing to use PHP to save images.

> The general idea is that you should not be downloading profile pictures to 
>   your server, for example by using PHP code. Instead, you should get the
>   URL of the picture (for example from the redirect header) and display
>   it using an image tag on the client side

But big sites like nametests(dot)com somehow manage to get user picture.

Here is a sample code I use to fetch the profile picture(atleast when it works)

```
function get_file($url) {
      //$url=$url."&token=".$this->token;
      $options = array(
                  'http' => array(
                      'method'=>"GET",
                      'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n".
                      "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2\r\n"
                )
              );

      $context  = stream_context_create($options);

      $data = "";

      $data = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

      return $data;
    }

$im = get_file("http://graph.facebook.com/897924100371841/picture");
echo $im;
```

Comment: Could this be a consequence of FB being a little more careful with users data after the recent debacle

Comment: Use an access token so Facebook knows who is downloading the image

Comment: @WizKid I'm using access token in my original script `graph.facebook.com/12345678/picture?token={token}`
I still get the same problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah probably but how does nametests[.]com work?

Comment: Where are you getting the user ID from and what type of access token are you using? Also what response are Facebook giving?

Comment: _“Instead, you should get the URL of the picture (for example from the redirect header) and display it using an image tag on the client side”_ - Any specific reason why you are not simply doing this instead?

Comment: @CBroe I need to use it in another image. see nametests[.]com

Comment: @WizKid I get id from facebook login using php sdk. and access token too

Comment: _“I'm using access token in my original script”_ - and did you use it _correctly_ there - or as currently shown in the code above? (Which would result in `.../picture&token=...`, which of course would be wrong.)

Comment: @CBroe then how am I supposed to use it?
`.../picture?token=...` is this wrong?

Comment: No, that would be correct; but that is not the URL your commented attempt at adding this in the above code would produce.

Comment: @CBroe oh that is because I add height and width in the url before using that function `.../picture?height=900&width=900&token=...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question.
It seems Facebook is rate limiting profile pictures. 
So after a number of requests it return null